# Create a column that identifies if all conditions are met

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, multiple-columns

I have a data frame with numeric values. I want to check, for each row if they meet a certain criteria, and create a new column which gives `TRUE` if all criteria are met.
Example criteria are `Current.eGFR` is greater than or equal to 15, or less than 60 and `Decline.12month` is less than or equal to -4.

This is `head()` of data frame

```
     ID Current.eGFR Decline.12month Decline.24.month
1   13         18.0            -1.3             -8.9
2   19         17.6             1.5             -2.3
3 1063         20.1            -5.3            -10.4
4  700         28.0            -0.2             -2.7
5 1518         14.6           -14.7            -45.2
6  197         19.0           -13.0             -5.1
```

Comment: This a basic logical condition question. Please show your attempt and any issues (errors/undesired result) so we can help with your learning curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that we need Current.eGFR >= 15 **and** Current.eGFR < 60 since all numbers would satisfy the condition if it were really **or**.  Compare:

```
1:70 >=15 | 1:70 < 60  # bad - result is *always* TRUE
##  [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
## [16] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
## [31] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
## [46] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
## [61] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

1:70 >=15 & 1:70 < 60  # good
##  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## [13] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
## [25]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
## [37]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
## [49]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
## [61] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Making that correction, use `transform` to create the new column.

```
transform(mydf, ok = Current.eGFR >= 15 & Current.eGFR < 60 & Decline.12month < -4)
```

giving:

```
    ID Current.eGFR Decline.12month Decline.24.month    ok
1   13         18.0            -1.3             -8.9 FALSE
2   19         17.6             1.5             -2.3 FALSE
3 1063         20.1            -5.3            -10.4  TRUE
4  700         28.0            -0.2             -2.7 FALSE
5 1518         14.6           -14.7            -45.2 FALSE
6  197         19.0           -13.0             -5.1  TRUE
```

### Note

The input `mydf` in reproducible form is assumed to be as follows.

```
Lines <- "     ID Current.eGFR Decline.12month Decline.24.month
1   13         18.0            -1.3             -8.9
2   19         17.6             1.5             -2.3
3 1063         20.1            -5.3            -10.4
4  700         28.0            -0.2             -2.7
5 1518         14.6           -14.7            -45.2
6  197         19.0           -13.0             -5.1"
mydf <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to to use the `>` or `<` along with `|` and `&`

```
df1$newcol <- with(df1, (Current.eGFR >= 15 & Current.eGFR < 60) &
               Decline.12month <= -4)
df1$newcol
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  FALSE  TRUE
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(13L, 19L, 1063L, 700L, 1518L, 197L),
Current.eGFR = c(18, 
17.6, 20.1, 28, 14.6, 19), Decline.12month = c(-1.3, 1.5, -5.3, 
-0.2, -14.7, -13), Decline.24.month = c(-8.9, -2.3, -10.4, -2.7, 
-45.2, -5.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Maybe `Current.eGFR >= 15 & Current.eGFR < 60` instead of `|`? As per the question, row 5 shouldn't be `TRUE`

Comment: @MalditoBarbudo  Thank you, updated.  I was literally following the OP's description.  thanks

Answer (score 2):

Tidy way, just for completeness:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(13L, 19L, 1063L, 700L, 1518L, 197L),
Current.eGFR = c(18, 
17.6, 20.1, 28, 14.6, 19), Decline.12month = c(-1.3, 1.5, -5.3, 
-0.2, -14.7, -13), Decline.24.month = c(-8.9, -2.3, -10.4, -2.7, 
-45.2, -5.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6"))

df1 %>%
  mutate(
    conditions_met = if_else(
      Current.eGFR >= 15 & Current.eGFR < 60 & Decline.12month <= -4,
      TRUE, FALSE
    )
  )
#>     ID Current.eGFR Decline.12month Decline.24.month conditions_met
#> 1   13         18.0            -1.3             -8.9          FALSE
#> 2   19         17.6             1.5             -2.3          FALSE
#> 3 1063         20.1            -5.3            -10.4           TRUE
#> 4  700         28.0            -0.2             -2.7          FALSE
#> 5 1518         14.6           -14.7            -45.2          FALSE
#> 6  197         19.0           -13.0             -5.1           TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Your code even works without the if_else statement. The following gives the same result: df1 %>%
  mutate(conditions_met = Current.eGFR >= 15 & Current.eGFR < 60 & Decline.12month <= -4)

Comment: @mharinga True, but I prefer the verbosity of the `if_else` in the answer. That way people can adapt the code to return not only logical values, but anything they want.